# Получить название открытого pdf-файла и номер открытой страницы

Tags: c++, pdf

У пользователя открыт "example.pdf" на странице 44.
Он выделяет текст в этом pdf-файле и жмет некоторые горячие клавиши 
(например, ctrl+c).
Программа добавляет в mytext.txt следующую запись:

```
файл: example.pdf, стр.44, дата добавления: 26.08.2019
<выделенный в файле текст>
```

Можно ли перехватить программными средствами название открытого файла и номер открытой страницы в этом pdf-файле?
Какими средствами лучше всего реализовать такую прогу?
Пригодится любая информация об этом!!!

Comment: Пользователь открывает файл в вашей программе или в сторонней?

Comment: для windows можно получить окно в фокусе, найти элемент окна который в фокусе, получить заголовок окна / элемента

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой путь - форкнуть готовый просмотрщик pdf, например [MuPDF](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/mupdf), найти подходящее место и дописать код.